# Is ordering by PK a good choice in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres with following 3 columns:
`pk:primary key, name::text, date1::date`

which sql will be faster if there are more than 1M rows in my postgres db

- select * from t1 order by pk
- select * from t1 order by date1
- select * from t1 order by name

Comment: The first query. You should try out all 3 queries and report back your findings.

Comment: The question is: which order do you need in your application? _That_ should drive what `order by` you use. If you don't care about the order, then leave it out completely - that will be the fastest query.

Comment: It's also going to depend on the hardware performance, memory configuration, average size of each row ... suppose all of the date1 or name values are the same, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clauses in each query require some kind of logical sort, to order records according to one of the columns.  For the case of ordering by the `pk` column, Postgres should be able to use the index that already exists on this column to sort in logarithmic time.  For the other two columns, if unindexed, Postgres will be forced to scan the entire table once.